# Compliance of 2x female connectors with male pin breakaway from another brand

Tags: connector, stepper-motor, ce, ul, compliance

For a product similar to a 3D printer I'm connecting 5x small Nema 8 motors and ground cables through a small 26x connector. The connector is enclosed and cannot be accessed from the user.

The motors operate with 12VDC, 0.6A/phase.

Due to shortages, the most practical solution would be to use:

- 2x [26x receptacle female socket](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0022552261/3044426) from Molex
- 1x [26x header breakaway](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/sullins-connector-solutions/PEC13DABN/860639) from Sullins

Would such a connection be compliant for the CE LVD? What about UL compliance too? These pins look well restrained, they are enclosed, the ratings are OK, that looks safe to me. But because these Molex connectors officially are not sold as wire-to-wire but instead as wire-to-board, and because I'm using a header brekaway from another brand I feel that some regulatory instance could complain. Am I overthinking this?

Thanks a lot for any hint

[image]

(I wanted to use [DF1B 26x connectors](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF1B-26DES-2-5RC/558470) from Hirose but I can't get the male pins in the US. I would have used the Hirose connectors and pins, thus making the connection trivially compliant I believe.)

Comment: What does the underwriter laboratory your getting your compliance cert from say?

Comment: Why are you concerned about compliance? This appears to be a one-off project for yourself, not a commercial product. Right?

Comment: @Passerby UL will come later, not in contact yet. CE LVD will be self-certification.

Comment: @DavideAndrea. Thanks. No, it's commercial (I'm asking here about the last parts that concern me).

Comment: Generally, if there's a chance that the connector may come lose and get exposed to humans (fingers etc during installation or use), then it's probably not compliant with safety standards. LVD only applies for supplies with >50VAC or >75VDC though, unless the product contains wireless electronics, then it applies indirectly through RED directive.

Answer (score 1):

> Due to shortages

There are plenty of appropriate connectors in stock right now. You don't have to resort to "Mickey Mouse" solutions. Be professional. Do not use unshrouded and unlatched connectors.

> Would such a connection be compliant for the CE LVD?

Not applicable.

> What about UL compliance too?

UL is voluntary, it is not a requirement. Regardless, cannot answer without a reference to a specific UL standard. Also, a UL certification involves testing of the entire product, it doesn't answer questions about a single interior connector.

EDIT:

> I need wire-to-wire connectors

If so, my [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&fl=00110030000000000000000000000000-500-%7C%7C26%7C%7C%7C) suggests these families:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- 3M - P50 P50E P50LE + P25E P25LE P50 P50E
- ERNI - SMC
- Harting - har-flex
- Harwin - Datamate L-Tek Trio-Tek (2r)
- Harwin - Datamate S-Tek
- Harwin - Gecko (w2b w2w latched female)
- Harwin - Gecko (w2b w2w latched male)
- Harwin - Gecko (w2b w2w unlatched)
- Harwin - Gecko SL
- Hirose - DF11 (crimp)
- Hirose - DF1B (2r w2w latch)
- Hirose - QR/P1
- Hirose - QR/P15 (sgnl)
- Hirose - QR/P18_ (mix)
- Hirose - QR/P4
- JAE - IL-AG5 (2r)
- JAE - MX17
- JST - JFA J1100 (2r)
- JST - RFC_ (2r mix)
- JST - RPZ
- JST - RWZ_ (mix)
- Molex - C-Grid (unlatch)
- Molex - Mini-Fit BMI
- Molex - MOX (2.54m 2r)
- Molex - MOX (2.54m 3r)
- Samtec - Mini Mate IPL1 IPM1 IPR1 MMTD MMTDT MRTD + IPD1 MMSD MMSDT
- Samtec - TFC TMF TFSD TFSDT + SMF SFMC SFML SFSDX SFC SFSD SFSDT
- TE - 0.64 (sealed)
- TE - AMP-Latch + 622 (latch 2.54m)
- TE - AMP-Latch + 622 (unlatch 2.54m)
- TE - AMPMODU AMP-Latch (2m)
- TE - AMPMODU Mod II Mod IV MT MTE (2r)
- TE - CT Hybrid Drawer (Mini-Drawer) adapter
- TE - Economy Power 2.5 (2r)
- TE - Hybrid mini-drawer
- TE - Junior Power Timer (unseal 2r)
- TE - Micro Quadlok MQS (2r plain unlatch)
- TE - Micro Quadlok MQS (auto)
- TE - Multi-Lock (3.5m 2r)
- TE - TH 025 (2.2m 2r)
- Wurth - WR-BHD (latched)
- Wurth - WR-BHD (unlatched)
- Wurth - WR-MM (latched)

Comment: Thanks a lot. OK, my suggestion was then Mickey Mouse, I wanted a confirmation there. I need wire-to-wire. Unless I'm missing something, Hirose DF1B has wire-to-wire options (e.g. DF1B-#DES-2.5RC with DF1B-#DEP-2.5RC, page 3 of their catalog). As suggested in other posts, I'll retreat to less cables per connector.

Comment: _ I need wire-to-wire_ The Hirose DF1 is either wire-to-wire or wire-to-board. I updated my comment to list wire-to-wire connector suggestions.

Comment: Thanks again, great selection tool. Feedback: is there a reason why Molex SL is not showing up?

Comment: _Molex SL_ : http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=standard_rect_conn&o=prismatic_2p54_conn&fl=N0000000000000000000000000000000-400-|||||

Comment: Sorry I was not precise: showing up in the list you added to your answer.

Comment: Because that is a list of wire-to-wire connectors and the Molex SL can be either wire-to-wire or wire-to-board. It's a limitation of my utility: if you look up the wire-to-wire connector section, it only lists connectors that are exclusively wire-to-wire. The workaround is to start from one-step-back: all the interior rectangular connectors. Then, they are all listed: wire-to-wire, wire-to-board, board-to-board.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about compliance, but all this looks slapdash to me.

My suggestion would be first, do not try to cram everything into one connector. Split the conduits by their function and use lower pin count connectors.

Second, try to arrange them so that all connectors would have different number of pins. This way you'd guarantee proper pairing.

Finally, use locking polarized connectors. You can find plenty of them in stock if you don't set your mind on something in particular. For example you can always find wire-to-wire [SM series](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SMP-02V-BC/1835574) JST connectors up to 18 pins.

Update:

Regarding space constraints, you should be able to find relatively small connectors for your requirements that will not take much more space. And you don't need many of them. For example 5+6+7+8 single row, or 12+14 dual row is all you need.

Also, don't ignore high density D-SUB connectors. Free hanging [HD D-SUB](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/adam-tech/HDT26-PR/9832582) are not much bigger than those Molex headers and available in wide range of pin counts. And they are polarized and can be "locked" with simple zip ties through mounting holes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. OK, no way around using correct connectors with their mating counterparts, and ideally with locking mechanism. I was packing them into 1x 26x connector because of space constraint. I see I'll have to retreat to split into smaller ones (can't upvote due to rep)

Comment: @thomast see an update re. space constraint

Comment: Thanks again @Maple. Good point about HD D-SUBs. I will likely settle with [Molex SL single row 12](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/0050579412/WM2910-ND/313613?itemSeq=384085436) + SL single row 13 (need 25 connectors).